# How can I structure this SQL Query the right way?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdh5b.png)

I need customers whose addresses contain (trial or avenue) when they pass it I need to get those people whose phone numbers end with 4

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share more details, and do that in readable form (that means: text)

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I only need romola as the answer because she is the only one who passes both condition. Who either has trial or avenue in her address and also her number ends with 9

Comment: you should put your ORs together using ( ) to make them a single condition.   `and (address like '%%' or address like '%%')` https://codepedia.info/sql-using-parentheses-with-and-or-condition-is-necessary-with-where-clause-to-gives-expected-result

Comment: **Please edit your question** to contain all relevant information